# Symlink generates empty alias file?

Tags: macos, symlink

I'm trying to create a folder that is going to contain all files that are in another folder.

This is the tree structure. I want to symlink `source` to `target`.

```
.
├── source-folder
    └── source <-- source folder
└── controllers
    └── another-folder
        └── yet-another-folder
            └── target <-- target folder
```

I tried

```
ln -s source-folder/source controllers/another-folder/yet-another-folder/target
```

but it only creates an empty alias file.

How do I create a folder that contains the same data that is in the `source-folder/source` folder?

Comment: You need to specify a full path for the source folder not a relative one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by placing myself in `yet-another-folder` and doing;

```
ln -s ../../../source-folder/source target
```

So I'm placed in the target's parent folder and the specified source path is relative to where I'm placed.

Comment: Don't you need another level of `..` there?  You need to go up 3 levels before you can come down to `source-folder`.

Comment: @JWWalker You are correct. My example tree wasn't the same as my real tree so that's why :).

Comment: Is a great workaround, I did `ln -s node_modules node_modules2` and then mv node_modules2 public`. It worked well but the answer from @Ben bellow seems to be more technically accurated.

Answer (score 13):

Better to create symlinks with full paths; it then works as expected

Comment: technically not required, *BUT* chances are you'll lose more time figuring out a wrong relative path - compared to the amount of time typing a full path.
generally speaking, using full path rather than relative path is more robust (IMHO)